# Cannot load keystore from system environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables

I have a simple spring boot application running on HTTPS with SSL enabled

application.properties

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=${SERVER_KEYSTORE}
server.ssl.key-store-password=${SERVER_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
```

where `SERVER_KEYSTORE` and `SERVER_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD` are system env variables

I generate a `jar` using `mvn clean package` and then run the executable `jar`. But I get the following error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8444 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8444, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

I have confirmed that port 8443 is not in use by any application.

Now, when I rewrite `application.properties` as

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=/etc/ssl.keystore
server.ssl.key-store-password=secret
```

The application runs fine on port 8443 with HTTPS. But I don't want to have the path and password part of my codebase.

I even tried specifying the complete path to the env file as

```
server.ssl.key-store=/etc/environment/${SERVER_KEYSTORE}
server.ssl.key-store-password=/etc/environment/${SERVER_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
```

It still gives the same error

Some help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I wonder why the error is for port `8444` when your props file says `8443`.

Comment: What is the value of `SERVER_KEYSTORE` and `SERVER_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD`?

Comment: You say it work with `/etc/ssl.keystore` but not with `/etc/environment/${SERVER_KEYSTORE}`. Well, it's not the same path, so why would you expect it to work for a different path?

Answer (score 2):

The following error clearly says that tomcat cannot stat on 8444 port. If you want to verify, open command prompt and type the command `netstat -a`. This will give you which are the ports already occupied. You can run in different ports like 8090, 8091 etc. Besides, if you want to know more details, start spring boot in debug mode using your ide.

> The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8444 failed to
>   start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be
>   misconfigured.

Comment: `netstat -a` does not list ports. I have already confirmed that there is no application running on the port. When I change keystore to actual values, it works. But when I use envs, it does not. Really frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess your question is how to read env properties in Spring application.properties. 
Try this : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-plugin/examples/run-env-variables.html